# How to query the average from a certain property in an Entity and return it in a List of List of objects in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, average

My entities designed in Entity Framework look like this:

Event

- EventId
- Date
- Acceleration
- Intensity
- DeviceId
- BlockId
- Device
- Block

Block

- BlockId
- DateStart
- DateEnd
- Events

Device

- DeviceId
- Alias
- ClusterId
- Cluster
- Events

Cluster

- ClusterId
- Name
- Devices
- RegionId

Region

- RegionId
- Name
- Clusters

An Event belongs to a Block and is registered by a Device. A Device belongs to a Cluster and a Cluster belongs to a Region.

What I'm trying to do is to get the average Acceleration and average Intensity of the Events in a Block, organized in objects in a List, these objects must be organized depending if I want to get the averages of the Events of a Block that were detected by the Devices in every Cluster or every Region.

What kind of query in LINQ should I use?

To make it more clear, these are the SQL string that represent the actions I want to perform

```
select avg(e.Intensity) as average from blocks b, events e, devices d, clusters c, regions r where b.blockid = 1 and b.blockid = e.blockid and e.uniqueid= d.uniqueid and d.clusterid  = c.clusterid group by c.clusterid;

select avg(e.Intensity) as average from blocks b, events e, devices d, clusters c, regions r where b.blockid = 1 and b.blockid = e.blockid and e.uniqueid= d.uniqueid and d.clusterid  = c.clusterid and c.regionid = r.regionid group by c.regionid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this (linq to entities)...

```
from ev in db.Events
where ev.Block.BlockID == 1
group ev by ev.Device.Cluster.Region.ID into g
// group ev by ev.Device.Cluster.ClusterID into g
select new
{
    RegionID = g.Key, // ClusterID = g.Key,
    AverageIntensity = g.Average(x => x.Intensity),
    AverageAcceleration = g.Average(x => x.Acceleration),
};
```

To add additional fields, e.g. Name:

```
group ev by new { ID = ev.Device.Cluster.ClusterID, Name = ev.Device.Cluster.Name } 
into g
```

or

```
group ev by ev.Device.Cluster into g  
// ...
ClusterName = g.Key.Name,
```

(SQL for both is the same)

> You effectively 'group by' many fields - but since all are the same
>   (i.e. if ID is the same, Name is the same) - you wouldn't change the
>   nature of the grouping - you just get additional fields attached.

Normally (w/o aggregation) you can also add the 'grouping' into select `Group = g,` and then flatten and return all records etc.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for, thank you so much. Just a quick question, if I to add the name of the Region or Cluster into the result, how should I do it? I tried `Name=g.Select(x=>x.Device.Cluster.Name)` but that returns the name of the Cluster/Region as many times as Events grouped in that Cluster or Region.